# Use Explain with Count

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In Rails there is a useful method that can show how long a query takes and what query it is.

The method is 'explain'

So I can do:

```
User.where(name: 'Johnny').explain
```

And it will display the actual sql query.

the 'count'  method also makes an sql query but since 'count' returns a number and not an active record, I cannot use explain on it.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `count` is not really a query - its a function that runs on query result.  The complexity will lie in the `FROM` and `WHERE` that will requiring `explain`ing.

Comment: `count` is a part of the SQL query and thus "really" a query. It is run internally inside the DB, not in rails.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
User.select('count(*)').where(name: 'Johnny').explain
```

EDIT: This is indeed *exactly* the same:

```
irb(main):004:0> Benutzer.where(login: 'xxx').count
   (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "BENUTZER" WHERE "BENUTZER"."LOGIN" = 'xxx'
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> Benutzer.select("count(*)").where(login: 'xxx').explain
  Benutzer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT count(*) FROM "BENUTZER" WHERE "BENUTZER"."LOGIN" = 'xxx'
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT count(*) FROM "BENUTZER"  WHERE "BENUTZER"."LOGIN" = 'xxx'
Plan hash value: 1339361075

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |    12 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BENUTZER |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("BENUTZER"."LOGIN"='xxx')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same as explaining the count method. If in complex cases the count method produce a sql query different from the select method, then this will not suffice.

Comment: See edit, it's the same. Sure, if there are complex cases (like ones involving distinct or order-by), then care has to be taken to "massage" the statement so the same code is generated.